# Why POST request creates new record if my code logic is for update?

Tags: node.js, rest

I read many articles like [https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/](https://RESTFULL%20API) and there is mentioned that, PUT is for update records and POST for create, because PUT is idempotent. It means if I will send the same request multiple times, it will not create new records instead of POST. But if my code logic is like, on the PUT request I create new record, or on the POST request I update record, why it doesn't work? code logic is more important right? because two of these methods body is similar.

Comment: Standard compliant code should make PUT idempotent, but there is no enforcement. Your server could just *not* do it. In fact it's very common for REST APIs to mutate on GET or modify on POST or create a new record on PUT, even though it is bad practice. Always check the individual API and make no assumptions based on the HTTP standards.